# passing variable from callback to express router

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, express

I am just starting to dive into node.js, and I have this issue I can't figure out.

I have this user I create in the file `passportAuth.js` and a callback to assure user created.

It looks something like this:

```
req.tmpPassport = {};
var fb = new fbgraph.Facebook(accessToken, 'v2.2');
fb.me(function(err, me) {
    req.tmpPassport.me = me;
    fb.my.events(function(err, events) {
        req.tmpPassport.events = events;
        fb.my.friends(function(err, result){
            req.tmpPassport.results = result;
            post_user();
        });
    });
});

//the callback
function post_user() {
    // this function is only executed after the callback from the async call
    return req.tmpPassport;
}
```

now, I want to pass the var `post_user()` returns to my express router which  is in a different file `routes.js` and render it like so:

```
router.get('/profile', securePages, function(req, res, next){
    res.render('profile', {title:'Welcome to aDating - Profile', user:--Pass Var Here--});
})
```

but I can't figure out how... I tried to require the module like this:

```
var fb_user = require('../auth/passportAuth.js');
```

and then use it like this:

```
   router.get('/profile', securePages, function(req, res, next){
        console.log(fb_user);
        res.render('profile', {title:'Welcome to aDating - Profile', user:req.fb_user});
    })
```

but it didn't work... could anybody help, please?

Comment: Routes are used to handle request from outside the app. If I'm not mistaking, it looks as if you are creating a user from a file, and then want to go to a route? Could you elaborate?

Comment: I will try to explain better...i am trying to create user and than render the data of the user, so if lets say user has property `name`, in the profile page i will be able to display this name...obviously only after this name is set, and this is why the `post-user` is there for

Answer (score -1):

In your custom module "passportAuth" you could return a javascript Promise and then use on your router, because require is a sync operation but your module is async, so, if you return a promise your router will have this appearence:

// fbUser is a javascript Promise object

```
var fbUser = require('../auth/passportAuth.js');
router.get('/profile', securePages, function(req, res, next){
    fbUser.then(function(data) {
        res.render('profile', {title:'Welcome to aDating - Profile', user:data.me});
     }).catch(function(err) {
         res.status(500).send(err);
     });
});
```

and your module fbUser is something like that:

```
module.exports = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    fb.me(function(err, me) {
        if(err) {
            return reject(err);
        }

        fb.my.events(function(err, events) {
            if(err) {
                return reject(err);
            }

            fb.my.friends(function(err, result){
                if(err) {
                    return reject(err);
                }

                var data = {
                    me: me,
                    events: events,
                    result, result
                };

                resolve(data);
            });
        });
    });
});
```